# grouped correlation loop in r

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between Col1 and all of the other columns for each group. My input data set looks like this:

```
Group1 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A       3    1    0    1 
A       8    0    1    0
B       4    1    1    1
B       2    1    0    1
```

And I would imagine my output dataset looks like this (numbers are fake, but represent the correlations)

```
Group Col1CorCol2 Col1CorCol3 Col1CorCal4
A        .7          .3           1
B         0          .4          .6
```

By the way, Col1 is continuous, and Col2, Col3 and Col4 are binary. There are also missing values.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: You could use one of the apply family solutions `t(sapply(split(df1, df1$Group1), function(x) sapply(3:ncol(x), function(i) {x1 <- x[,c(2,i)]; cor(x1[,1], x1[,2])})))` or use `dplyr/data.table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD[,-1, with=FALSE],
                    function(x) cor(x,Col1)) , by=Group1]
setnames(res,2:4, paste0('Col1Cor', names(res)[-1]))
```

You can specify the `use` option in `?cor` for removing the "missing values"

EDIT: here is what the data looks like that is giving me the error:
http://postimg.org/image/g9rfkamod/

Comment: I am taking your advice and trying the "use" option; I wrote this:
res <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD[,-1, with=FALSE],
                           function(x) cor(x,nps.rating, use = "complete.obs")) , by=Group1]
setnames(res,2:4, paste0('Col1Cor', names(res)[-1]));;;;

But I get this error still:
Error in cor(x, nps.rating, use = "complete.obs") : 'x' must be numeric

Thoughts? - I have also run str - all my Col1 to Col4 are numeric.. some other columns are not

Comment: @blast00 Could you post the dput of a small dataset that shows this error

Comment: here is a picture of the dataset that is showing this error: 
http://postimg.org/image/g9rfkamod/

Comment: @blast00 A picture is not useful as I cannot copy the data.  It is better to dput it

Comment: I think I got it to work once I got removed some of the useless columns. What should the output look like?

Comment: @blast00 Glad to know it works.  The reason why I suggested `dput` is to reproduce the problem.